# Average cells that are in a table based on info within another cell of the same table

Tags: excel, average, excel-tables

[image: table]
I have a table created and I'm wanting to average the pH(total scale) column based on the date column, specifically by year. The dates range from 2011 to 2020, so I'm hoping for an average of pH from all the days listed in 2011, all the days listed in 2012, etc. Is there a way to use the averageif function to do this? I'm not entirely sure if I know how to do the criteria portion to select based on only year. There are a LOT of data points, so simply selecting them would be a huge hassle and I'm hoping there's an easier way to do this.

Thank you for any help!!

I tried this but it failed
=AVERAGEIF(Table1[[#Headers],[Date]], 2011,Table1[[#Headers],[pH (total scale)]]) how do I go about fixing this? Do I have the range and average_range correct and I just need to change the criteria, or did I get all 3 parts wrong?

Comment: PIvot table would help a lot in this case. Also 1/1/2011is not equal to 2011. Create helper column with =YEAR(your_date) formula and use that column instead of Table1[[#Headers],[Date]],

Comment: You should use either `AVERAGEIFS` or `FILTER` and your criteria should be (for the year 2011):`">=" & Date(2011,1,1)` and also `"<=" & Date(2011,12,31`.